# Intersect polygons returns true instead of geometry

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry, overlapping-features, st-intersects

I try to do a simple cut between two layers and PostGIS returns a boolean instead of a geometry

```sql
select
    t1.id,
    st_intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom) geom 
from
    public.table1 t1 
inner join
    public.table2 t2 
    on st_intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom);
```

I tried to specified for each geom, `::geometry` but i get an error:

> cannot convert boolean type to geometry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the geometry use the [`ST_Intersection()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html):

> Returns a geometry representing the point-set intersection of two
> geometries. In other words, that portion of geometry A and geometry B
> that is shared between the two geometries.

```sql
select 
    t1.id,
    st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom) geom  --Here!
from
    public.table1 t1 
inner join
    public.table2 t2 
    on st_intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom);
```